# Were black actors more prominent in the 80s than they are now?

Tags: casting, cinema-history

Lately I've taken a mild interest in 80s pop culture, and from my very superficial look I was surprised to see more black actors in movies, tv shows, and commercials of that time than I'm used to seeing today.

One example: Miami Vice, which aired in the second half of 1980s had a white and a black guy as protagonists. I was genuinely surprised by this because, honestly, I think this would be considered unusual, maybe even radical in any mainstream show today that's not overtly targeted at a black demographic. Instead, what we usually see is the token black guy (Jesse L. Martin, Ice T) in an otherwise white cast. Even a show like Chicago PD, a show about a city that's whose population and police force is something like a third black--even a show like that still has the minimum required one token black guy and that's it.

Another example: Looking at sitcoms, I think I can name more black sitcoms from the 80s and 90s (Cosby, Fresh Prince, Moesha, Martin, Moesha, Family Matters, Sister Sister) than contemporary ones (Blackish..., and that's it?). I admit that this list probably says more about me than about the state of TV. I haven't kept up with sitcoms. And, who knows? maybe the 80s and 90s were the golden age of sitcoms and they've since fallen in popularity and so there's just fewer sitcoms overall, and hence fewer black sitcoms. Fine. But still, that's a precipitous drop.

I'm not trying to start a flame war, or start a discussion about the merits of representing minorities on screen. I'm just looking for thoughtful answers on 1) whether this pattern of higher representation of black actors in the 80s is real or spurious and 2) if real, what could cause this paradoxical drop in representation despite the conventional narrative of racial progress. References would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/tv/la-et-st-tv-film-diversity-20160224-story.html

Comment: ..also "representation" is a wide target. For instance, Chicago PD has two women and a hispanic actor...so there's only so much room to go around.

Comment: I don't have any sources on this, but I do know that as a kid in the 80s I often heard the term "[Blaxploitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaxploitation)" in reference to these predominantly black-cast shows... Perhaps sometime in the late 90s/early 00s there was a PC backlash against the term, and therefore the practice of making shows with casts made up of all one ethnic group?

Comment: @Steve-O - Blaxploitation was mostly used in reference to 1970's movies that captured the "blackness" of the ghetto society and were made specifically for the black audience.  Shaft, Super Fly and Willie Dynamite were some great blaxploitation films.  I think what happened in the 80's was influenced by Spike Lee's films, and some of that carried over into present day with Tyler Perry's films.

Comment: There's a great video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEiXGrqoFMs&list=LLQSEAXu306aVj6hLYHs_Pyw) about the rise and falling trends of black sitcoms. Worth a watch.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I thought that blaxploitation films often were highly stereotyped, so that the "blackness" they captured was more what (mainly white) producers and directors imagined was the case. Or is that not correct?

Comment: Why the close votes? This seems like a reasonable question asking for objective information - is the pattern they noticed real, and what are the likely causes of it if it is real.

Comment: I agree this does not seem like a question that begs an opinion, but rather one that begs some degree of factual response. Looks like some people were afraid of what might be found in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[*Empire*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3228904/), [*Insecure*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5024912/), [*Queen Sugar*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4419214/), [*Secrets and Lies*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3516878/), [*House of Payne*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0773264/)...  There are still shows out there that cater specifically to the black audience, just not all of them are available to all TV subscribers.

Additionally, I've noticed a very large trend in commercials lately that depicts a black male/white female household.

In movies, there's usually a good balance between black and white characters, although some still remain all-white and some remain all-black.  Tyler Perry's movies feature predominately black characters, although with a few recent duds his movies seem to come out less frequently.  There have also been conscious attempts to inject black characters into white roles, but they are usually met with bad results.  Starting with a horrible remake of [*The Honeymooners* (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373908/) that featured Cedric the Entertainer and Mike Epps, up through the latest reboot of [*Fantastic Four* (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502712/) that featured black actor Michael B. Jordan in the traditionally white role of Johnny Storm, there's a trail of films that tried to use black actors in traditionally white roles to appeal to a broader audience.

Comment: This doesn't address the 1980s, so it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: But addresses what OP said was existing in the 80s and shows that it still exists now.

Comment: How does one determine if a show "cater[s]  specifically to the black audience".

Comment: If a show cast contains a majority of blacks and covers topics blacks relate to, it's pretty self-explanatory.  Empire is about a Hip Hop mogul.  Need I further explain?

Comment: But the shows cites by the OP *didn't* cater specifically to black people. With the exception of Sister, Sister and maybe Moesha, they were mainstream shows.

Comment: Just to add some other shows or miniseries, remake of Roots, Underground (since cancelled), Claws (TNT), The Good Fight, The Wire (Lance Reddic was a co-lead with D. West for all four seasons), Lethal Weapon (Tv series FOX), Bosch (Jamie Hector co-lead. He is Hatian), Empire, Luther, Undercover, Scandal, How to get Away with Murder, Orange is the New Black, etc